# Is HTTP Basic Authentication and OAuth 2.0 same?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

One of a vendor API documentation mentions that their API calls require to use HTTP Basic Authentication scheme, i.e. user:password Base64 encoded but, their token API (Login equivalent) documentation mentions that "***..this service implements OAuth 2.0 - Resource Owner Password & Credential Grant***"

> Isn't HTTP Basic Authentication different from OAuth ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, HTTP Basic Authentication different from OAuth 2.0. However, the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) utilizes Basic Authentication Scheme within the Authorization Request for the Client's credentials as described with [section 4.3.1. Authorization Request and Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.1)

The Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant is typically used to convert legacy systems to OAuth 2.0 and no more secure than [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617).

Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant is intended to be used when no other Grant Types are available and ONLY when there is a high degree of trust between the Resource Owner and the OAuth Client .

Comment: >high degree of trust<  Is this because, end-user (resource owner) provides his/her userid and password to this trusted 3rd party client (instead of providing it to the Authorization server in other grant flows) and this 3rd party client makes call to the authorization server ?

Comment: and HTTP Basic Authentication technique (of using Authorization header and base64 encoded credentials) is used by the trusted 3rd party app to send the user credentials to Authorization Server. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant does not utilize the Basic Authentication Scheme. It rather uses its own scheme to pass a username and password as POST parameters.

Comment: @HansZ. is correct, but the Client DOES use HTTP Basic Auth. (Edited answer for clarification)

Comment: @yathirigan -  Yes, it is this because, end-user (resource owner) provides his/her userid and password to this trusted 3rd party client

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be any client authentication method or even none

Comment: I agree with Hanz. In an OAuth2 context, the basic authentication is used to authenticate confidential clients, not users. User credentials are sent throught the POST body request.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they both are different.
Http Basic : This is for authentication and user credentials are encoded then passed in HTTP header to the client server.
Basic example for HTTP Basic : Just like traditional web application which asked user to provide credentials and these credentials sent to server in HTTP header. Later server utilize those credentials to authenticate  the user.

OAuth 2 : This is for authorization, here the client server required authorization of user data(resource owner) from authorization server.
Basic example for OAuth 2 : Let say there is a online game application running on a server, the user accessed the application which starts loading into user's browser. Now that application asking grants from user to post data about games on his Facebook account. Here user authorize his that application to access his Facebook posts through OAuth Standard. Refer the internal mechanism https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Answer (score 4):

`Basic access authentication` usage is comparable to `OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Type`.

A session can be created using `Basic Authentication` and services can be accessed using a `sessionid` in a stateful environment.

But if you do not want to use the session due to session limitations or stateless services, you can use the `OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Type` instead, which creates a token instead of session and `sessionid`. This token provides access to the services.

Answer (score 3):

**HTTP basic access authentication:**
This is the simpler method for meeting the requirements to access a web service. It is simple because it doesn’t require any of the usual processes in a credentials system: cookies, session IDs or access pages. The whole HTTP basic authentication process is based on standard fields in the HTTP header. Thus, it avoids handshaking: the automated process by which two entities establish authenticated communication before starting normal communication via the established channel. This means equipment can communicate with an external device only if there is successful authentication; otherwise, the communication channel is not created. The connection via modem would fail, for example. The secure development of the basic HTTP access authentication method is HTTPs.
To prevent the basic HTTP access authentication method causing the browser to launch a username and password request for each access, the browser must store this information in the cache for a prudent length of time that doesn’t reduce security excessively. These security credentials are usually stored for 15 minutes.

What is this basic HTTP access authentication method like in the real world?

1. The access credential provided to third-party developers who want to connect to a mobile API is a totally secret alphanumerical ID.
2. This alphanumerical API key is stored in a secure space on the server.
3. The developer making requests for a particular service contained in this API should place this secret ID within the HTTP authorization header along with the word Basic. The two elements together allow the server to recognize the alphanumerical credential and provide access.

GET /private/index.php HTTP/1.1

Host: example.com

Authorization: Basic alphanumerical ID

**OAuth 2.0:**
OAuth represents a step forward in the use of credentials for authentication of API service users. It is a major advance on the basic HTTP access authentication method. Today it is practically the only security method that is almost 100% reliable, and its reliability is based on creating unique authentication tokens for each user. If this access token is compromised, it is deleted and a new one is issued. This means that the API’s own credentials are safeguarded.
The authentication process is as follows:

1. A user launches a native application and is asked to give a username or email address and a password to identify themselves as a user.
2. The type of request used to send this credential to the API is a POST request, which ensures private delivery of secret data. This request is sent via the SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) protocol, designed to enable applications to transmit outbound data securely. SSL facilitates giving and receiving encryption keys between applications.
3. This request allows to validate user credentials and to create ad hoc an authentication or access token that will expire after a time, or if the user or developer responsible for the API believes it to have been breached.
4. This authentication token is stored in the device to facilitate access to the API’s services that support the application itself.

If we compare both methods, OAuth 2.0 provides better security criteria because any initial request for credentials is made under the SSL protocol and because the guaranteed access object is a temporary token. In the basic HTTP access authentication process, access to API services always relies on sending credentials via the web, specifically in the HTTP header, which makes it much vulnerable to third parties.