# How to make both Basic Auth and OAuth 2.0 work together for Mule APIs while testing via POSTMAN?

Tags: api, authentication, postman, mule, raml

I have a Mule Application which has a REST Http endpoint. The API has both Basic Auth and Oauth defined in its root RAML file. Now that it supports both these Auth types, when I test to call the API via POSTMAN, I could only see one "Authorization" token generated in the headers.

> How can I pass both?

The API is responding with a **403 Forbidden**. I am not entirely sure what is causing this issue, but how could I rule out the error cause by trying to pass both the Basic Auth and Oauth Bearer tokens to the API call.

But my main question is:  **Is it possible to use both the AUTH types at the same time for an API Call?**

I am open to try any suggestions.

Comment: Can you add info related to how you have implemented these Authentications? There is no such thing as passing both Authorizations in a single request.

Comment: Both Basic Auth and OAuth use the `Authorization` header. Basic Auth sends a `Basic` value in this header, and OAuth sends a `Bearer` value. You can only send one or the other; you can't send both.

Comment: there is another question posted here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411661/is-http-basic-authentication-and-oauth-2-0-same      that you can refer to understand both basic Auth and Oauth